# Akka-Http custom rejections doesn't work in the latest version

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I was trying out custom `RejectionHandler` in akka-http as given in the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/rejections.html#customizing-rejection-handling). Following is a minimal working code of what I was trying.

```
object MyApp extends App {
  implicit def myRejectionHandler =
    RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
      .handle {
        case m: MethodRejection =>
          complete((StatusCodes.NotFound, "Not here!"))
      }.result()
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()

  val route: Route =
    path("index") {
      post {
        complete(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    }

    Http().newServerAt("localhost", 8080).bind(route)
}
```

If I try `http://localhost:8080/index`, the response is

```
HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: POST
```

with status code `405`,instead of

```
Not here!
```

with status code `404`

My `build.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"

lazy val akkaVersion = "2.6.17"
lazy val akkaHttpVersion = "10.2.7"

libraryDependencies ++=
  Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % akkaVersion,
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % akkaHttpVersion
  )
```

The sample given in doc for `akka-http` **10.1.x** works.

Comment: What's the actual type of `myRejectionHandler`? Aren't you missing a `.build()` at the end?

Comment: @GaëlJ, thanks for pointing it out. I had missed adding that. Added `.result()` as it's the scala API.

Comment: And it's still not working?

Comment: @GaëlJ, no. I have `.result()` in my local setup. I had accidentally deleted it when I copy-pasted and reduced the code complexity.

Comment: I tried locally and indeed it doesnt work implicitly but does with the route wrapped with a `handleRejection(myRejectionHandler) { ... } ` . The line `Http()...` binding the route to the interface used to accept the implicit rejection handler but I cant find it anymore.

Comment: @ccheneson, yes it works with handleRejection. I was going through the code for a bit to check where exactly the implicit rejection handler was accepted in `10.1.x`, as the deprecated `Http().bindAndHandle` also doesn't work in the version `10.2.7`. But couldn't find that too.

Comment: Might be worth opening an issue on Akka's GitHub, so that they either fix the documentation or the code ;)